# How to fix the error when data augmenting TensorFlow training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to data augment my TensorFlow model's training data. My model runs without data augmentation. I want to augment training data to improve results. This is my attempt:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory_testData,
    #validation_split=0.2,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
 
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory_testData,
    #validation_split=0.2,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
 
model = create_functionalModel()
 
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800)
```

I then ran it and am getting these errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1c89b4a3fc84> in <module>()
     30     epochs=50,
     31     validation_data=validation_generator,
---> 32     validation_steps=800)

 
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     61     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 663552 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 30976
     [[node model_4/flatten_4/Reshape
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/flatten.py:96)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4555]
```

It seems that this issue is related to the input shapes required by my model. Can you please help me understand how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model requires an input of shape (180, 180)
But you are resizing your images to (150, 150).

Changing:

```
target_size=(150, 150),
```

To:

```
target_size=(180, 180),
```

Should fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that :( I'm getting a warning "WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 800 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset." Currently I have about a 1000 images per class for training my dataset. Can you please help me understand how to set these steps_per_epoch and validation steps parameters?

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer fixed your problem, don't forget to mark it as "accepted answer". As for the new problem, use floor(the amount of data/batch_size)) for the number of steps per epoch so that you train only on the number of images available.

Comment: How should validation steps be selected?

Comment: You apply the same rules. With the number of images available to the validation_generator

Comment: So you're recommending that steps per epoch and validation steps are equal?

Comment: since you disabled splitting: #validation_split=0.2. Then yes

Comment: I want to enable splitting when creating the training dataset. Uncommenting #validation_split results in an error. How can I split the training dataset when augmented data?